# Your lover cursed you into an ogre!

Tags: popularity-contest

You're a programmer. You always work everyday and don't have time with your lover.

One day, your lover was so angry with you that they cursed you into an ogre! Your fingers have grown big, and you can't type as before. And of course only your lover can lift your curse , but you only have **3 days**! So, you decided to write a program to touch your lover's heart and lift your curse. It can be a love letter, or something just saying I'm sorry; it's up to you. Try your best.

Of course because you are an ogre now, when you type you press two keys on your keyboard at a time, horizontally. Example: when you want to type  <kbd>S</kbd>, you only have the choice of either  <kbd>A</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd>,  <kbd>S</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> input. You can change the order to <kbd>S</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> -- it's just matter of luck and time.

**Note :**

1. The big and edge keys of the keyboard are not affected (<kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>caps lock</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd>). However, you only can use a big key **3 times**, and then the key breaks.
2. Other than key on left-bottom side area also only can use **3 times** due lack of durability against ogre hand.
3. Using mouse input (ex: virtual keyboard, copy paste) is considered not creative enough to show your love, and will curse you into stone.
4. Your keyboard is PC US English QWERTY keyboard.
5. Convince your lover with the most votes !

Comment: If I want G can't I do `G+H`, `backspace`? I don't see how this adds any challenge at all.

Comment: ahh, sorry i will update the role

Comment: Also, no mouse input right? (trivial to type all the ASCII characters and then copy-paste)

Comment: @StevenLiao will curse you into a.. dust?

Comment: How about arrows? Like I want to type "YOU" using "YU", then go left, then press "OP" resulting in "YOPU", then "backspace" to delete "P".

Comment: i'm adding some rule for other key against ogre fingers

Comment: To the author: I think you should clarify the limit for all keys on the keyboard (Home, End, arrow keys, Num Locks, numeric key pad, function keys, etc.).